# Continuous time markov Chain Intensity Matrix + Steady State

Tags: markov-chains

For the continuous time markov chain, the rate matrix Q can be defined with diagonal elements
$$Q_{ii}=-\sum_{i\neq j}Q_{ij}$$
My question is this.  Since the stationary distribution is defined such that $Q\vec{\pi}=0$ and the matrix Q is defined as above, is there any situation in which $\pi$ is not just defined as $\vec 1$?

Comment: "Since the stationary distribution is defined such that $Q\vec{\pi}=0$..." Nope. Please reread your notes.

Comment: So that is what my notes say.  The internet says pi Q = 0 defines pi...

Comment: Hmmm... would you disclose the source of your notes then?

Comment: From a class.  No textbooks.  But since I have a rate matrix, not a transition probability (exp(Rt)), then the stationary distribution would satisfy piQ=0 and not pi Q = pi, right?

Comment: "But since I have a rate matrix, not a transition probability " - sounds like you need to study the Kolmogorov forward/backward equations.